# How to get email id and address from contacts

Tags: android, contacts

Hi i am trying to get email address from android contacts.i am trying like below but from this code i am getting ph number pls help me.

```
Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, null);
    String email = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the DataKind to Email.  Try this:

```
Cursor pCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
String email = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
```